# Numb3rs TV series - Antenna

Tags: electromagnetism, antennas, noise

Most of you might have watched the TV series 'Numb3rs'.

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numb3rs

In one of those episodes they were discussing about how to capture the contents on the screen of a computer using just an antenna. Now I don't remember in which episode it was. But I am curious to know whether such scenarios possible practically?

> http://www.math.cornell.edu/~numb3rs/

Please add that episode name If anyone remembers it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't see the episode, but it may be referring to "Phreaking", by which the signals from a CRT monitor can be listened-in on (it uses high frequency changing currents to display the information, so these will inevitably result in some RF radiation from which this information can *in principle* be extracted).

Wikipedia [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_Eck_phreaking) has a bit more info.